# When to add members to a prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In the below code,

```
function Stack() {
    this.stac = new Array();
    this.pop = function () {
        return this.stac.pop();
    }
    this.push = function (item) {
        this.stac.push(item);
    }
}
```

How to decide whether `push` and `pop` are instance members of `Stack` class (shown above) or members of `Stack.prototype`?

Comment: The methods that are common should be defined on prototype, why are they defined on each instance

Comment: @Tushar common to what?

Comment: Common to all instances.

Comment: By using this constructor function you can instantiate many individual objects, each with an array in it. But you don't need to create the pop and push functions in each object since they are exactly the same. So you define them at the Stack.prototype since Stack.prototype will be assigned as prototype to all objects instantiated by this constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write it inside of a class every instance of that class will have its own *push* and *pop* methods, so you redefine those methods for every instance. 
If you define those methods for prototype all instances will share those methods. 
So you can easily change those methods on the run for every instance if you want. Otherwise you have to rewrite those methods for every previously created instances.
Defining methods via **prototype** is considered **a good practice**. It's faster, better and it makes inheritance easier!

Check [Addy Osmany - Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

If you want to check whether property is from a prototype or from the instance you can use this:
`instanceName.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)`

In your example:

```
function Stack() {
    this.stac = new Array();
    this.pop = function () {
        return this.stac.pop();
    }
    this.push = function (item) {
        this.stac.push(item);
    }
}

Stack.prototype.notAnOwnProperty = 12;

var stack = new Stack();

console.log(stack.hasOwnProperty('pop'));
console.log(stack.hasOwnProperty('notAnOwnProperty'));
```

You will get:

```
true
false
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3a3saLbs/)

Answer (score 2):

The properties and methods which are defined inside constructor function are the properties of that object. These are not shared between instances.

The simple rule is

**Anything that is added on `this` instance inside constructor function is private to that instance**

You can use [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) to compare if different instances points to the same method.

**Your Code:**

```
function Stack() {
    this.stac = new Array();
    this.pop = function () {
        return this.stac.pop();
    }
    this.push = function (item) {
        console.log('In push');
        this.stac.push(item);
    }
}

var stack = new Stack(),
    stack2 = new Stack();
console.log(Object.is(stack.push, stack2.push)); // false
```

---

**Recommended Way:**

It is recommended to add the common shared properties and methods on prototype. These properties and methods are shared between object instances.

```
function Stack2() {
    this.stack = new Array();
}
Stack2.prototype.pop = function () {
    return this.stack.pop();
};
Stack2.prototype.push = function (item) {
    console.log('In push');
    this.stack.push(item);
}
var stack = new Stack2(),
    stack2 = new Stack2();

console.log(Object.is(stack.push, stack2.push)); // true
```

Comment: Cool, this actually answers the original question `How to decide whether push and pop are instance members of Stack class(shown above) or members of Stack.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Lends answer you also want to add properties and methods to the prototype when you want to inherit that object in another object and use them within the child object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance means re-usability, and if needed gives liberty to override functionality, by hiding already written method. In above example, if you want to Inherit(Make Parrent Object) `Stack` further and want to give default `push` and `pop` functionality to its inherited objects, in that case you should put `push` and `pop` function in `Stack.prototype`. this will give inherited object(child object) liberty to use default `pop` and `push`  methods or override these methods(by declaring new one with same name).

For further reference for Portotype Pattern please follow 
[Prototype Pattern](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/the-prototype-pattern-structuring-javascript-code-part-ii)

Explained with example on pluralsight
[Using the JavaScript Prototype Pattern](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/the-prototype-pattern-structuring-javascript-code-part-ii)